# IIS FastCGI Minimum Fastcgi processes

Tags: perl, fastcgi, iis-8

I have developed an app in Perl using the Catalyst framework.

Web Server: IIS 8.5
deployment: FastCGI

Question: I have set App pool's Worker Processes=1 and  FastCGI's MaxInstances=4. when the app pool restarts, it starts up with 2 instances of my perl exe and as the site load increases that number goes up to 4 as expected. Is it possible to configure minimum number of Fastcgi processes when the app pool starts? I would like it to start all 4 processes if possible.

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/q/270202/156128